# How to prevent my method from creating a folder named "null"

Tags: java, null, directory

I'm having a small unexpected issue when it comes to creating new folders inside my program. Here's my method where i create my directory:

```
public void createDirectory() {

    directory = new File("C:/Users/Lotix/Desktop/TestFolder/"
            + categoryName);
    boolean isDirectoryCreated = directory.mkdir();

    if (isDirectoryCreated) {

        System.out.println("Created new directory in: " + directory);

    } else if (directory.exists()) {

        System.out.println("Category already exists!");

    }

}
```

Here's my listener method where the method is called:

```
if (e.getSource() == addButton) {

            System.out.println("Add Button Clicked");
            botTextArea.setText("");
            botTextArea.append("Adding new category...");

            popUp.newCategoryPrompt();
            System.out.println(popUp.getNewCategoryName());             
            Category cat = new Category(popUp.getNewCategoryName(), "test tag" );
            cat.createDirectory();

        }
```

And the prompt method itself:

```
// Prompt to enter name of the new category
public void newCategoryPrompt() {

    JFrame newCatFrame = new JFrame();
    newCategoryName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(newCatFrame,
            "Enter the name of new category");

}
```

**What's the exact issue?**

Program is supposed to create a folder in the already existing directory. However, **when user decides to close that prompt without giving a name to a new folder, it creates a folder named "null" regardless**. How do i prevent it from happening?

My temporary solution (although very sloppy) is to let user create that folder (by accident or not) and let it be since my program will print out an error and won't create it if the folder with such a name in that directory already exists.

EDIT: Same thing happens when you press cancel.
EDIT2: Added the prompt method.

Comment: You did not post the code for popUp.newCategoryPrompt(), so what does it actually do? There must be a way to check in this method whether the user cancelled, and return a boolean false which can be evaluated to see if you need to create the directory?

Comment: @copeg Edited it just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Category cat = new Category(popUp.getNewCategoryName(), "test tag" );
if(cat.getCategoryName() != null)
cat.createDirectory();
```

You will need to change getCategoryName() to the getter of the category name in the Category class.

Comment: This solved my problem instantly. Thank you very much. You appear to understand my program better than i do. I need to get it more organised.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to bypass blank and null values both:

```
Category cat = new Category(popUp.getNewCategoryName(), "test tag" );
if(cat.getCategoryName() != null && !"".equals(cat.getCategoryName())){
      cat.createDirectory();
}
```